Why is $ULU=NU$ (a refinement of $|N|=q^{n^2-n}$)?
Let $G=GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, $U$, $L$, $N$ the subsets of upper-triangular unipotent, lower-triangular unipotent, all unipotent matrices respectively. Then $ULU=NU$ means that for any $g\in G$ the number of $ULU$-decompositions of $g$ equals to the number of $NU$-decompositions. More precisely, the following two sets have equal size:

triples $(a,b,c)\in U\times L\times U$ such that $g=abc$

pairs $(a,b)\in N\times U$ such that $g=ab$


I checked this on a computer for small $n,q$, and also
it is straightforward to reformulate this as an identity in the center of the Yokonuma-Hecke algebra and I think I have a proof using this interpretation, but I didn't write it down.
This can be seen as a refinement of the famous identity $|N|=q^{n^2-n}$ (just sum over representatives of $G/U$), which now has a combinatorial proof.
What I'm asking is a combinatorial (bijective) or geometric proof of this identity.
Equivalent formulation: in each coset $G/U$ the number of unipotent matrices equals to the number of matrices in $UL$ (matrices whose trailing principal minors are $1$).
